# Shell Script: function with argument to compute number of files

Tags: shell

I need to write a function that takes directory location as argument and computes the number of files for that directory.

`file_count()`
`{  LOCATION=$1`

```
FILECOUNT=$(find $LOCATION -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
echo "$FILECOUNT"
 }
LOCATION1=/etc
echo "$LOCATION1" 
file_count LOCATION1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working for you...  other than that, in your example, `file_count LOCATION1` on the last line should be `file_count $LOCATION1`.   Could that be what's tripping you up?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Silly mistake. It is working now. The find command should have $LOCATION1 instead of $LOCATION.

Comment: Um, I think that's not correct...  `LOCATION` is the local (to the function) variable that holds the passed location.  If it works, it's because it inherits the value of `LOCATION1`.  Try something this: `unset LOCATION1` and then `file_count /otherdir` where "otherdir" is something other than the dir you used previously, to make sure it works without LOCATION1 defined.  I suspect that when you changed the find command, it ignored what you passed when calling the function and used the value of LOCATION1 instead.  What you passed was "LOCATION1", not the value of `$LOCATION1`.